# Android(4.4) - Notification sound not playing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-notifications

This is a very common question, but I did not find an answer to it. I created app with Xamarin.Android. My app creates a locale notifications (with time delayed), it works except android 4.4(on emulator and device). 
My device: Samsung GT-I9195, Android 4,4,2

This is my code create notification (in BroadcastReceiver):

```
 var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)
                    .SetContentText(notification.Body)
                    .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)
                    .SetAutoCancel(true);

 builder.SetDefaults(NotificationCompat.DefaultAll);
```

In this case, only vibro works.

I tried other options, for example:

```
builder.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alam));
...
//load embeded sound
Android.Net.Uri alarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"{ ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}:{CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.sound}");
builder.SetSound(alarmUri);
```

I even tried to launch a media player(in OnReceive).

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.Create(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext, alarmUri);
mp.Start();
```

But all this does not work. Only vibration, without sound. Any ideas?

Comment: it works on my device(5.0),you try to delete "builder.SetDefaults(NotificationCompat.DefaultAll);" only use "builder.SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alam));"